# Can I list all registered event sources?

Tags: c#, event-log

My windows service writes to the event log, but I've had various problems getting this correct. So in the process I used a number of different names. I followed an article describing how to set up event logs in windows services. So after adding an EventLog component in the designer, I have added this to the constructor:

```
if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("AS0604"))
   System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource("AS0604", "SIRR");

eventLog1.Source = "AS0604";
eventLog1.Log = "SIRR";
eventLog1.WriteEntry("AS is initializing...", EventLogEntryType.Information, 16);
```

I found out that there is trouble if the source has the same name as the service name of the windows service. But I kept changing the names a lot for both the Log and the Source. The

```
EventLog[] eventLogs = EventLog.GetEventLogs();
```

Lists the eventlogs and I was able to remove those I didn't use with EventLog.Delete command.

But how does this work? Are there still registered sources in these deleted logs? Can I get a list of registered sources?

Answer (score 14):

Since the accepted answer is lost, here is another. Unfortunately I found no alternative to examining the Windows Registry directly.

- `PowerShell (Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\<EventLogName>).pschildname`

E.g. to list the Windows **Application** Event Log's Sources:

- `PowerShell (Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Application).pschildname`

I threw this up after reading several sources. Unfortunately none were very clear or direct.

Comment: Great, helpful answer.  Thanks. I had an Event Log name which had a space in it so if you alter the code to include double-quotes around the HKLM string then it works for all. 
Example: (Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\<Event Log Name with spaces>").pschildname

Answer (score 1):

via powershell:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Application |Select-Object Source -Unique
```

see: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/48d1e34d-6ded-4039-a8a4-3b17d9c69488/list-eventlog-sources?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: This doesn't show ALL registered sources. If there's no entry currently in the log for given source it won't be shown here.

Comment: @dstarkowski is correct. This gets all events currently in the Application event log and then lists their distinct (unique) sources. That is very likely just a subset of registered sources.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a C# answer, but here is a WMI solution:

```
$Sources = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\cimv2" -Class "Win32_NTEventLOgFile" | Select-Object FileName, Sources | ForEach-Object -Begin { $hash = @{}} -Process { $hash[$_.FileName] = $_.Sources } -end { $Hash }
```

This will list the source even if there is no entry currently in the log for the given source.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell you can also run the following to find the Windows event log **Source**s for a given event log (event log such as `Application`, `Security`, `System`, or any custom event log).

```
PS C:WINDOWS\system32> $log=Get-WmiObject win32_NTEventlogfile -filter "filename='Application'" 
PS C:WINDOWS\system32> $log.sources
```

The above will return all **Source**s for the **Application** event log.

My current company's software creates a custom Windows event log Source for each version of ASP.NET that the application has been upgraded to.   Here is a PowerShell example where I have:

1. Added a new Log/Source (event log `Application`, source `ASP.NET 7.7.0`)
2. Aggregated the Sources into `$log` variable
3. Requested output and filtered sources for those that start with `ASP.NET` (I had not yet written any events to this log/source).

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> New-Eventlog -LogName Application -Source "ASP.NET 7.7.0"
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $log=Get-WmiObject win32_NTEventlogfile -filter "filename='Application'"
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $log.sources | where{$_ -like "ASP.NET*"}
ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0
ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0
ASP.NET 4.8.4075.0
ASP.NET 4.8.4084.0
ASP.NET 4.8.4200.0
ASP.NET 4.8.4210.0
ASP.NET 4.8.4250.0
ASP.NET 4.8.4330.0
ASP.NET 4.8.4465.0
ASP.NET 4.8.4494.0
ASP.NET 4.8.4654.0
ASP.NET 4.8.4662.0
ASP.NET 4.8.9195.0
ASP.NET 7.7.0
ASP.NET Version:4.8.4084.0
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```