# How to find the correct protocol name Eventlog c#

Tags: c#, windows, service, event-log

my task: 
I want to display entries from the windows eventlog from my printjobs. 
I found various tutorials from msdn and different sites, but I cannot get access to my preferred protocol/service name.

Microsoft-Windows-PrintService

```
    my Code ( c#): 
 string lists = EventLog.LogNameFromSourceName("Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational", ".");
```

but this code is not working. Did somebody know a solution or a workaround for my problem. 
This is my first project in  c#.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: do you have any error messages?

Comment: Do you see any events in your system that has the specified source ("Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational")? If so, in which log do you see them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax for the call is correct.  I think the source you are specifying in the call probably doesn't exist.

If you call EventLog.SourcesExists("Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational") does it return false?  If so, then the source string you are passing is incorrect and you need to find the correct source from Event Viewer.

Edit:  In response to your later post, I don't think permissions have anything to do with it.  I was able to access "Application and Services Logs" sources without doing anything special.

According to this previous post [event log sources cannot be listed from the API but must be mined from the registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563585/can-i-list-all-registered-event-sources).  However, I did find an application [EventLogSourcesView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/event_log_sources_view.html) that can generate a list of all event sources.  It may be helpful in finding the source you are looking for.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your help! I can not identify the right path to the events log, but I take an other way to fetch the print jobs ( Actually, I read the jobs with WMI) . but thank´s for all hints!

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your reply.

Yes, the SourceExist Method return false. 
Hmm.. I have no idea how to find the correct Service name.

The SoruceExist Method returns true, for all protocols which are listed under the "Windows Protocols"-section, only. The other protocols which are located under the section "Anwendungs- und Dienstprotokolle" ( I use a german windows version -  maybe translate to "Application-and Serviceprotocols"), the method returns false.

In this location, the log will be saved at

```
 %SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\Microsoft-Windows-PrintService%4Operational.evtx
```

Did I need special permissons to "enter" these logs ( Currently, Visual Studio is started as Administrator, only .. enough?)

Thanks!